# My app is getting a request timeout H12 error when i deploy it to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, request

I was recently working on a small Url-shortener as an exercise and locally it runs fine, but when i tried to deploy it to Heroku it gives me an H12, request timeout error, can someone help me find where the I messed up.I have asynchronous functions in my code but I don't know what function could be causing the timeout.

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
    <h1>URL Shrinker</h1>
    <form action="/shortUrls" method="POST" class="my-4 form-inline">
        <label for="fullUrl" class="sr-only">Url</label>
        <input required placeholder="Url" type="url" name="fullUrl" id="fullUrl" class="form-control col mr-2">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Shrink</button>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Full URL</th>
                <th>Short Url</th>
                <th>Clicks</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% shortUrls.forEach(shortUrl => { %>

          
            <tr>
                <td><a href="<%= shortUrl.full %>"><%= shortUrl.full %></a></td>
                <td><a href="<%= shortUrl.short %>"><%= shortUrl.short %></a></td>
                <td><%= shortUrl.clicks %></td>
            </tr>
           <% }) %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ShortUrl = require('./models/shortUrl');



const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/urlShortener', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
})

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}))

app.get('/', async (req, res)=> {
    const shortUrls = await ShortUrl.find()
    res.render('index', { shortUrls: shortUrls});
});

app.post('/shortUrls', async(req, res)=>{
   await ShortUrl.create({
        full: req.body.fullUrl
    })
    
    res.redirect('/')
})

app.get('/:shortUrl', async(req, res)=>{
  const shortUrl = await ShortUrl.findOne({ short: req.params.shortUrl }) 

  if(shortUrl == null) return res.sendStatus(404)

  shortUrl.clicks++
  shortUrl.save()

  res.redirect(shortUrl.full)

})


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server running at ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: is it the database connection?

Comment: No, I believe it has to do with the request I'm making.

Comment: I actually read more in to the error and I do see that is a problem with the mongoose database connection. but I don't see what is wrong with it.

Comment: you probably aren't using localhost as your connection string to mongodb in production on heroku, correct?

Comment: yes sorry for the late response, I don't think I am.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are saving and sending the redirect before the document is saved (saving returns a promise), add `await` in front of the save

```js
await shortUrl.save()
```